# Latex compiling with "redefined" commands

Tags: compiling

is there a way to pass these strings:

```
\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}}
```

by command-line?

I tried:

```
 latex "\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}} \input{myfile.tex}"
```

but, obviously, it doesn't work because the compiler complains about "`\includegraphics` is undefined" (at that point). Any idea to fix that?

Comment: Why do you want to do something cruel like this?

Comment: @Johannes_B I need to "temporarily" compile this way to visually check what figures need to be trimmed. It would be a command called by an emacs script.

Comment: Would using a different page colour an alternative way to judge what needs to be trimmed?

Comment: @Johannes_B Nice idea! I'll give it a try! (but how to do that by command line?)

Comment: `\RequirePackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{yellow!50!white}` (untested)

Comment: You could try on the commsnd line `\AtBeginDocument{....}`. (untested)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! It works! You solved my problem. I think you should post a complete answer to my question so I could accept it.

Comment: Related: [Load a package by command line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/375516/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delay your redefinition by using `\AtBeginDocument{....}`:

```
 latex "\AtBeginDocument{\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}}} \input{myfile.tex}"
```