# Load a package by command line

Tags: compiling

is there a way to load a package by command line? I tried:

```
latex "\RequirePackage{xcolor} \input{myfile.tex}"
```

but it doesn't work.

I need to load some packages "temporarily", by scripts I wrote, to do some checks on my output files (pdf or dvi).

Edit. I found that the string I use generates the file `xcolor.pdf` instead of `myfile.pdf`

As requested, this is my `.log` shell output:

```
tmp$ latex "\RequirePackage{xcolor} \input{example.tex}"
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2015/10/01> patch level 2
Babel <3.9m> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
(./example.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lipsum/lipsum.sty)
No file xcolor.aux.
[1
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
map/pdftex.map}
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!] [2
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!
Non-PDF special ignored!] (./xcolor.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/f
onts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on xcolor.pdf (2 pages, 22276 bytes).
Transcript written on xcolor.log.
```

and this is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Check if you need double backslashes

Comment: Could you enlarge on 'doesn't work': it should. Perhaps your shell needs the backslash escaping (often as two backslashes).

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/375512/latex-compiling-with-redefined-commands

Comment: @JosephWright I get the `package.pdf` file instead of `filename.þdf` ones... also with double backslash excaping.

Comment: @JosephWright Thank you for your hint ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Driver mismatch

The file `myfile.tex` is broken:

> ```
> tmp$ latex
> ```

`latex` is initialized to generate DVI as output format.

> ```
> (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
> ...
> (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def))
> ```

Package `xcolor` is loaded with DVI driver `dvips`. Fine.

But then:

> ```
> Non-PDF special ignored!
> {/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/upd
> ```
>
> map/pdftex.map}
>       ...
>       Output written on xcolor.pdf

The mode switches to PDF and a PDF file is generated.
Color specials for DVI have no effect.

The LaTeX document should *never* change the output mode. Many, many packages relay on a stable output mode. Check the code for changes of `\pdfoutput`. It may be read (better is the use of package `ifpdf`), but should not be changed.

## Loading a package on the command line

There are packages, that can be loaded *before* `\documentclass` using `\RequirePackage`, see egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375526/16967).

Other package require to be loaded after the class. Some of them, can be loaded
even quite late in `\AtBeginDocument`, then the command line would become:

```
$ pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{yellow}}\input{myfile}'
```

An alternative is providing a hook in the file `myfile.tex`. For example, at the right place in the preamble:

```
\ifx\WithPageColor Y
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \pagecolor{yellow}
\fi
```

If `\WithPageColor` is undefined, the page color setting is ignored. But, it can be defined on the command line:

```
$ pdflatex '\let\WithPageColor=Y\input{myfile}'
```

Another variant for the hook in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{...}
...
\providecommand{\PageColorHook}{}
\PageColorHook
...
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Then on the command line:

```
$ pdflatex '\newcommand{\PageColorHook}{\usepackage{xcolor}{\pagecolor{yellow}}\input{myfile}'
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, that's true: the *first* input file is used for the name.

How to fix it?

```
latex -jobname=myfile '\RequirePackage{xcolor}\input{myfile.tex}'
```

On your system, double quotes may work, on mine they don't.

---

Why does that happen? When a TeX engine starts with

```
engine <options> <argument>
```

(in your case `engine` is `latex`)

it looks at what it is fed with. If the `<argument>` does not start with a backslash, it is considered a file name and essentially the engine executes `\input <argument>`. Otherwise the engine waits for the first `\input` instruction and the name of the input file will determine the job name, used for the log file and the output (dvi or PDF).

Note: the `\input` command is the primitive one.

Since `\RequirePackage` eventually does `\input xcolor.sty`, we have that the jobname is set to `xcolor` because of the rules.

The option `-jobname` fixes it by disabling the above feature and establishing the jobname at the outset.

There is a big difference between the command line call above and when the input file starts with `\RequirePackage`. In the latter case, `\RequirePackage` is seen when a file has already been `\input` and the jobname decided upon.

Comment: OK, but why it doesn't work it I do: latex -jobname=example '\RequirePackage{xcolor} \AtBeginDocument{\pagecolor{yellow}} \input{example.tex}'?

Comment: Sorry, your answer to my question is correct. I'll need to post another answer to point my problem.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi That's a completely different problem. And a bug in the new color drivers for TeX Live 2017. `:-(`

Comment: @egred Thank you! You're really great! But I'm using Tex Live 2015.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi See http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-June/040357.html and http://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2017-June/040359.html

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi I get the background color when using TeX Live 2015.

Comment: I really thank you. I do not get the background color but Heiko Oberdiek solution fixed my problem. There's a "titans fight" here ;-) . You "LaTeX people" are very great!