# Trim margins of the entire document (by command line)

Tags: crop

Is there a way to trim the margins of the entire document by `LaTeX`? I need to do that temporarily, to make more comfortable my typesetting work. I figured out to pass this option by command line with the `\AtBeginDocument` [technique](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375533/33634) but a preamble solution is also welcome.

To better explain my purposes I'd like to get the same result that I can achieve with the `bash` command (that here works because of the coloured page):

```bash
pdfcrop --margins '-50 -50 -50 -50' mydoc.pdf mydoc.pdf
```

E.g. for the code:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

%% \usepackage{xcolor}
%% \pagecolor[HTML]{E4EDE9}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

I want to change the layout from:

[image]

**NOTE.** I obtain this layout by passing the color option by command line:

```bash
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\RequirePackage{xcolor} \pagecolor[HTML]{E4EDE9}} \input{Latex.tex}'
```

(I want to thank Thérèse for this very eye-relaxing background color)

to:

[image]

An okular specific solution is welcome but, since I use many viewers, I prefer a LaTeX solution.

**NOTE2.** I need a solution that **does not** change the text layout. I need only to trim the `pdf` as it stands.

---

**SOLUTION**

I want to share the solution that works in my case (thanks to Steven B. Segletes). This is the code for a command line cropped and coloured compilation:

```bash
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\newlength\DX \DX=3cm \paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax \hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax \newlength\DY \DY=3cm \paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax \voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.1\DY-.5\footskip\relax \RequirePackage{xcolor} \pagecolor[HTML]{E4EDE9}} \nonstopmode\input{mydoc.tex}'
```

**NOTE ADDED.** After TeX Live 2020 October update this solution needs an update: [Trim margins of the entire document by command line (after TeX Live 2020 update)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/583685/33634)

Comment: you can specify the page size via geometry package, or simply set `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` directly

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not able to use the `geometry` package with my documents because it messes up my standard layout. With `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth` the document is not centered but trimmed on bottom and right margins. What is my mistake?

Comment: geometry only changes the typeset layout if you tell it to do so, setting pdfpageheight and pdfpagewidth will just change the size so trim from right and bottom but you can always re-adjust with \hoffset and \voffset

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Really, I can't understand. Even if I use just `\usepackge[a4paper]{geometry}` in my preamble my layout is messed up. How can I tell geometry to not do so?

Comment: geometry has an option `passthrough` or somesuch that says not to change anything, or of course you can use geometry rather than primitive length settings to set all your document. If you use `a4paper` option that tells geometry to set the text block for 14 paper size so does set the typesetting related lengths.

Comment: Why not use a pdf viewer which can zoom to textwidth? For example the internal viewer of texstudio is capable to do this

Comment: @samcarter I have hundreds of emacs functions and okular has a good forward and reverse search with emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I take the baseline `article` documentclass (using the `pass` option of `geometry`) and change the `\paperwidth` and `\paperheight` by the specified amount and then associated margins (actually `\hoffset` and `\voffset`) by one half of the page change dimensions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\newlength\DX
\DX=3.5in
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax
\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax
\newlength\DY
\DY=2.8in
\paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax
\voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.5\DY-.5\footskip\relax
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Without any changes:

[image]

Comment: This. with some calibration, works for me. Thanks al lot!

Comment: One more thing. Is it possible to pass these strings by command line? I tried to put all that stuff in an `\AtBeginDocument` command but it does not work.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi Not quite sure how to pass it by command line.  But you could place `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\newlength\DX
\DX=3.5in
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax
\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax
\newlength\DY
\DY=2.8in
\paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax
\voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.5\DY-.5\footskip\relax` in a separate file, and then `\input` that file in the preamble.  To not trim it, you could just place a second blank file with the name of the `\input` file.  That is, alternate whether the input file is blank or contains those commands.

Comment: Done! You don't need the geometry package for this solution! I compiled with `pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\newlength\DX \DX=3cm \paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax \hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax \newlength\DY \DY=3cm \paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax \voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.1\DY-.5\footskip\relax} \nonstopmode\input{mydoc.tex}'` and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @GabrieleNicolardi That's a neat technique

Answer (score 7):

Why don't you use `crop` package?!

As David Carlisle said you can also use `geometry` package, but I prefer `crop` in this case; for more details see the package's manual.

with setting width and height you can achieve your desired margins.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4,center,noinfo,cross, width=13.5cm,height=22.5cm]{crop}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works with my simple example but I'm not able to make it works with my working documents layout...

Comment: The problem I have is that the pages are trimmed only on the right-bottom. Can you help me with that?

Comment: I have no idea about that, maybe your are using a class or packages thta redefines the margins. It's better to make a MWE that shows the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not allowed to do that. :-(

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
\edef\mt{\the\textwidth}%
\edef\mtt{\the\textheight}%
\RequirePackage{geometry}%
\geometry{paperwidth=\dimexpr\mt+1cm\relax,
paperheight=\dimexpr\mtt+1cm\relax,margin=.5cm}
\RequirePackage{xcolor} 
\pagecolor[HTML]{E4EDE9}}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}
\blindtext

\blindtext

\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the same problem as with the crop package. I solved with Steven B. Segletes solution.