# Trim margins of the entire document by command line (after TeX Live 2020 update)

Tags: distributions, command-line

I'm used to compile my `.tex` files with this command:

```bash
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\newlength\DX \DX=3cm \paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax \hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax \newlength\DY \DY=3cm \paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax \voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.1\DY-.5\footskip\relax \RequirePackage{xcolor}} \nonstopmode\input{test.tex}'
```

I'll write it here in a more readeable way:

```bash
pdflatex '\AtBeginDocument{\newlength\DX
          \DX=3cm \paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax
          \hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax
          \newlength\DY \DY=3cm
          \paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax
          \voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.1\DY-.5\footskip\relax \RequirePackage{xcolor}}
          \nonstopmode\input{test.tex}'
```

See [Trim margins of the entire document (by command line)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/380146/33634)

But after the last update to the October release of TeX Live 2020 it doesn't work anymore.

This is a MWE. My file contains:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{jheppub}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I want an output as if it were:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{jheppub}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\newlength\DX \DX=3cm
\paperwidth=\dimexpr\paperwidth-\DX\relax
\hoffset=\dimexpr\hoffset-.5\DX\relax
\newlength\DY \DY=3cm
\paperheight=\dimexpr\paperheight-\DY\relax
\voffset=\dimexpr\voffset-.1\DY-.5\footskip\relax

\begin{document}

\blindtext 
\blindtext
\blindtext\footnote{\blindtext}

\end{document}
```

[image]

but I don't want to change my `.tex` file. I need to do it by command line.

Now, after TeX Live 2020 update, I get:

[image]

where the trimmed margins are wrong. I think that the probles is caused by something in the `jheppub.sty` file.

You can find the `jheppub.sty` file here: https://jhep.sissa.it/jhep/help/JHEP/TeXclass/DOCS/jheppub.sty

Comment: I get the same output with TeX Live 2015, 2018, 2019, and 2020.  None look like your desired output...

Comment: Ok, ok. I have also `\RequirePackage{xcolor}` after `\relax` because of other things I do. I updated my question.

Comment: Hm... Strange.  With `xcolor` there I also get the same output with those four versions (which is what I expected), but the output now looks like the output you want (including with TeX Live 2020).  What I find odd is the presence of  `xcolor` changing the margins...

Comment: Indeed I need a working solution without `xcolor`.

Comment: So your problem is not at all related to updating, but to the inclusion or not of `xcolor`

Comment: Sorry, I finally found what cause the error. Is something in the package `jheppub` that I usually use in my editing work. But the different behaviour was introduced by the update. I need to heavily update my question.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I update my question with a real MWE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the new LaTeX `\AtBeginDocument` commands from the user ("top-level") are executed last, after all other `\AtBeginDocument`.

This means that if you change the page layout there, you are reponsable to set *all* relevant values. No code in graphicx or color or geometry will do it for you.

In your case you are missing to set the pdf page values:

```
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
```

An alternative is to use an earlier hook:

```
  \AddToHook{begindocument/before}{<your code>}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution that works with both the new LaTeX and the previous releases? I need to do it by command line, without changing my .tex file. I tried to set the `\pdfpage` stuff into `\AtBeginDocument` but it doesn't work.

Comment: adding `\pdfpageheight=\paperheight \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth` to your command should work with both (assuming that you use pdflatex).

Comment: You're right! It works! Many thanks!